# Insert element(s) in a row of a matrix [MATLAB]

Tags: matlab, matrix

Say, I have a  matrix A

```
A = [1 0 0 0 1 0 ;0 1 0 0 0 1;0 0 0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0];

A =

    1     0     0     0     1     0
    0     1     0     0     0     1
    0     0     0     1     0     0
    0     0     1     0     0     0
```

I want to add a zero in the third column of the second row. To maintain the same dimension of A the last element of the second row, i.e., one has to be removed too.

```
A =

     1     0     0     0     1     0
     0     1     0     0     0     0
     0     0     0     1     0     0
     0     0     1     0     0     0
```

How do I do these two steps in a single line of code?

Further, if I need to perform the same action in the fourth column of the third row, is there a way to perform both second and third rows action with a single line of code and without using loops?

Also, I may need to insert more than one zero in a particular row.

Lastly, I am going to be dealing with matrices with dimensions 1000x1000 and greater, so I need to have a really fast code.

Can anyone help me with these issues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A for loop is fine in this case, it faster than calling to function handles:

```
function [ A ] = InsertValue( A, RowColVal )
    % example: RowColVal=[2,3,0; 4,1,0.3; ];
    for i=1:size(RowColVal)
        row=RowColVal(i,1);
        col=RowColVal(i,2);
        val=RowColVal(i,3);
        A(row,col:end)=[val, A(row,col:end-1)] ;
    end
end
```

Script to test:

```
A = [1 0 0 0 1 0 ;0 1 0 0 0 1;0 0 0 1 0 0;0 0 1 0 0 0];
%A=rand(1000);
RowColVal=...
    [2,3,0; 
    4,1,1;];
[ A ] = InsertValue( A, RowColVal )
```